# How To Read #define's from C++ header file with C#

Tags: c#

I want to read `#define's` from C++ header file but I can't do that. How can I do that?

Example:

```
#define EXAMPLE_DEFINE_ONE          (10)

#define EXAMPLE_DEFINE_TWO          (99)
```

What i want:

```
Output: EXAMPLE_DEFINE_ONE

Output: EXAMPLE_DEFINE_TWO
```

Comment: do you want to read the text from c++ file??

Comment: no i want to read only #define's from C++ file

Comment: Do you understand that that's just text?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the text file and then use the regular expression `^#define\s+(\w+)` to capture it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\Data.txt"))
        {  
           if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Contains("#define"))
          {
            list.Add(line.Split(new[] { ' ' }, 
                   StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]);
          }
        }

         foreach (var line in list)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: Well, OK, now you have the text in memory.  Doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: You still haven't solved the problem... take a look at my answer.

Comment: @emodendroket: yes now my code only reads the `#define` statements

Comment: The sample output clearly showed that #define would be removed too, which is why my regex has a capture.